# Add CGAL lib using CMakeList (Ubuntu) / 3D mesh generation

Tags: c++, git, mesh, cgal, 3d-modelling

I'm trying to use the lib CGAL to do 3D meshes reconstruction. I would like to test some exemple available on the [website](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/index.html), but now to do it properly...

What I did :

- Download source from the [git](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal) (release 4.10)
- Installed the dependency (not all but a part)
- And run a cmake-gui .. which provides this after configure step :
  [image]

But when I doing the following includes :

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <CGAL/trace.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
//#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
//#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
//#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3.h>
//#include <CGAL/make_surface_mesh.h>
//#include <CGAL/Implicit_surface_3.h>
//#include <CGAL/IO/output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron.h>
//#include <CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h>
#include <CGAL/Point_with_normal_3.h>
#include <CGAL/property_map.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/read_xyz_points.h>
//#include <CGAL/compute_average_spacing.h>
//#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/distance.h>
```

Only the uncomment work.

What I did to check :

- I my cmake

  find_package(CGAL REQUIRED)
  MESSAGE("=======================")
  MESSAGE("${CGAL_USE_FILE}")
  MESSAGE("${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  MESSAGE("${CGAL_LIBRARIES_DIR}")
  MESSAGE("=======================")

  LIST(APPEND INCLUDE_DIRS ${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  LIST(APPEND LIBRARIES    ${CGAL_LIBRARIES_DIR})

(the list part is to provides access to libraries to all module in cmakelist by doing

```
FILE(GLOB APPFILES "app/*.cpp")
FOREACH(APPFILE ${APPFILES})
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(APPNAME ${APPFILE} NAME_WE)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(${APPNAME} ${APPFILE})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${APPNAME} ${LIBRARIES} )
ENDFOREACH()
```

)
which display :

```
=======================
/usr/local//lib/CGAL/UseCGAL.cmake
/usr/local//include
/usr/local//lib
=======================
```

- Moreover when I'm runing cmake .. I got this :

  WARNING: Target "testCGAL" requests linking to directory "/usr/local//lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

  WARNING: Target "testCGAL" requests linking to directory "/usr/local//lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

(testCGAL is the name of the class to test the import).

I don't understand why the comment part of my includes do not works. Is someone able to say me why or is able to give me a piece of advice ?

Thanks

PS : By the way, I would like to do 3D meshes reconstruction from depth map (and corresponding color) or colored point cloud. Moreover I would like to get a textured mesh. Does someone know a good lib to do this ?

=============== EDIT ============

At the end when I run cmake .. and make all compile but I got the following error message :

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testCGAL.dir/app/testCGAL.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/testCGAL
CMakeFiles/testCGAL.dir/app/testCGAL.cpp.o: In function `CGAL::Interval_nt<false>::Test_runtime_rounding_modes::Test_runtime_rounding_modes()':
testCGAL.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb0EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC2Ev[_ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb0EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC5Ev]+0xd2): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
testCGAL.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb0EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC2Ev[_ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb0EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC5Ev]+0x180): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
CMakeFiles/testCGAL.dir/app/testCGAL.cpp.o: In function `CGAL::Interval_nt<true>::Test_runtime_rounding_modes::Test_runtime_rounding_modes()':
testCGAL.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb1EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC2Ev[_ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb1EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC5Ev]+0xd2): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
testCGAL.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb1EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC2Ev[_ZN4CGAL11Interval_ntILb1EE27Test_runtime_rounding_modesC5Ev]+0x180): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/testCGAL.dir/build.make:352: recipe for target 'bin/testCGAL' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/testCGAL] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:302: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/testCGAL.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testCGAL.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you forget the show us the error messages you get?

Comment: Yea sorry, I have updated my question to provide it.

Comment: you aren't linking with CGAL (you are adding a directory to the list of libraries). Please check again the instructions on how to use cgal with cmake.

Comment: I understood it. Most par of people are doing like describe here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37116452/6239104 to include cgal. But as I shew with the cmake message, for me, it link to a .cmake file. So it is still not a lib. I also check on http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html they say " If found, the variable CGAL_USE_FILE is set to a compilation environment CMake file. Including this file within a CMake script sets up include paths and libraries to link with CGAL and essential third party libraries.".

Comment: But when I used it I got /usr/local//lib/CGAL/UseCGAL.cmake: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status